# Estimate of Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $h(z):\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is holomorphic with $|h(z)-z^2|<1$ if $|z|=1$- Then I've got to show that this implies $|h'(0)|\leq 2$.

Well, I choose the Cauchy Integral formula and try to estimate with the ML-bound:
$$
|h'(0)|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1}\frac{h(z)}{z^2}dz\right|\leq\max_{|z|=1} \frac{h(z)}{z^2}\leq 2
$$ 
because of the bound $h(z)-z^2<1$ and $z^2-h(z)<1$

I think my proof, in particular the last step, is wrong. How can I estimate correctly? Can we also use the maximum modulus principle here?

Comment: $h(z),z^2\in\mathbb{C}$  so it does not make sense to write $h(z)-z^2<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that 
$$
|h(z)-z^2|<1 \iff \left|\frac{h(z)}{z^2}-1\right|<\frac{1}{|z|^2}=1\:\text{ on }\:\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}
$$
Then, by the triangle inequality you have 
$$
1>\left|\frac{h(z)}{z^2}-1\right|\ge\left|\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right|-1\iff \left|\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\right|< 2
$$
Finally
$$
\begin{split}
|h'(0)|&=\Bigg|\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\mathrm{d}z\Bigg|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{|z|=1}\bigg|\frac{h(z)}{z^2}\bigg|\mathrm{d}\ell<2 \frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{|z|=1}\mathrm{d}\ell=2
\end{split}
$$

Comment: To the downvoter: why the downvote?